# How can I round the edges of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, objects

I have looked at other similar questions on this site but couldn't answer my question. I have a model made of cubes the edges look very sharp (I would put a picture here but I don't have the required rep) is there a simple way to make the edges round?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could use the [Bevel Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier) from the properties panel.

[image]

Example with *Segments* set to 3 and *Width* 0.1 (red cube) *Width* 0.3 (blue cube)

[image]

Answer (score 37):

[stacker's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2535/12) answers the question. However, you can also selectively bevel parts of your mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> which is often faster than using the modifier if you want to bevel certain parts of your mesh *(the modifier has options where you can bevel a group of vertices etc)*. You can also bevel single vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

See a quick example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/how-to-make-2-curves-for-an-urban-street-corner/2485#2485). It is worth noting that you can set your [mesh shading to smooth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-with-hard-edges) to help remove faceted geometry at times and give a more rounded look.

Also see [Most efficient way to round edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/811/12) and [How can I make sharp geometric 3d models look more realistic?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247/how-can-i-make-sharp-geometric-3d-models-look-more-realistic/) for more tips.

Answer (score 13):

You can also decide to do it the manual way. Add loop cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> close to the edges of the cube in all directions *(or as needed)*.

Then apply a subdivision surface modifier <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1 - 6</kbd>

Comment: Your answer is ultimately the better solution but one con is that it generates much more geometry than is needed. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/811/12

Comment: Yes. The modifier is actually the best option in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

If somehow your mesh is all messed up and you're looking for a way to avoid selecting multiple outer edges, the [*Remesh modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html#remesh-modifier) can sometimes yield adequate results.

This applies in cases when you need a more photorealistic edge to objects - it WILL NOT give you full control of bevelling. Whether it's the best way also depends on the complexity of your shape(s) and how much else is going on in your final render. The more complexity, the harder for the modifier to get it "right".

For increased accuracy, set the voxel size really low (save first, even save as if necessary). This operation better be well thought through though, as it drastically slows things down. Keep in mind your intended end result before going this route.