# Nice normal map without beveled edges

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, edges, normals

I've got mesh with lots of holes, concavities and convexities. The problem is that it has no beveled edges and whole mesh is badly triangulated. I only need to bake a good normal map, but adding bevels requires to totally remesh it which will take so much time :/ Is there any quicker way to do that? Maybe I can get around this somehow? Maybe there's another map I can bake and transform  to normals with some PS plugins? BTW I'm going to bake it with xNormal (I have never baked anything straight with blender).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/20997/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10787/599

Comment: As i said adding bevels will require to remesh whole model cause of bad triangulation all over it.

Comment: What about simulating bevels with OSL? (see the first link)

Answer (score 2):

Selecting one side of your mesh

[image]

Use inset <kbd>I</kbd> to get a border of quads

[image]

Repeat for surrounding sides

[image]

Select the boundary of the side and add a bevel.

[image]

With the faces of one side selected you can use Select Boundary Loop (in the select menu) to get the outer edge loop to bevel.