# Fill a frame with a sphere

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to create a smooth round surface onto a rectangle frame...without having strange appearances on the surface of the object. As seen on the pic, the inner circle should fill the whole frame that is around it. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: The smooth corners of the mesh could be created with using loopcuts and positioning them just near corners. Sharp edges might be done with mean crease.

Comment: I would fill in the rectangle, add some loopcuts to get a decent amount of geometry, then turn on proportional editing with [O] with a spherical falloff and pull the center vertex out.

Comment: Do you want the whole square rounded up like a pillow or just a sphere rising in the centre of the flat square?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I am modeling a Macbook Pro and the surface it nothing like just extruding the rectangle and scale every new extrusion to get a smooth roundish surface. Thats why I came up with the idea to put a circle into the shape of my rectangle. So it is not just building a pillow or a simple dot rising in the middle of the mesh. I will try to use proportional editing though and see where it will get me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @SebastianJaeger The bevel modifier could help see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/how-can-i-round-the-edges-of-a-mesh/2535#2535

Comment: @SebastianJaeger is this a duplicate of this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/how-to-create-a-smooth-surface-onto-a-rectangle-frame ? Then my answer should work here also.