# Cause of Frayed Edges

Tags: modeling

I am working on a computer tablet. Attached the screen shots of edit mode and object mode of the "to be" screen of this computer tablet. What is causing these frayed edges and how to solve that ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's because the topology isn't the way you think it is. From the menu in Edit Mode, Select > Non-Manifold and Blender will show you where there are problems. Then zoom in and look closely at what's happening. These sorts of artifacts can occur if you fill edges or faces in with the wrong part of your geometry selected and don't notice it at the time.

Comment: Thanks !! Is it possible to "remove" the non-manifold stuff and repair the mesh or is that too difficult ?Non-Manifold are faces that don't have 4 vertices ?

Comment: fix these two faces that are making a mess out of your geometry: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUBF.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/tnCV5.png

Comment: Jan, if you use the key sequence Mentalist supplied in his comment (Select > Non-Manifold), and switch to face select mode, the first step is  to delete "Just faces" to clean up the mesh. Then it may be necessary to clean up a non manifold edges, too, using delete "just edges and faces".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're some faces with twisted vertices the scaled model reveals them:

[image]

To fix it remove the faces and recreate them by selecting the edges followed by <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

You might also want to consider to remove the loop cut in the upper part.

Related:

- [What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)
- [How to create a smooth surface onto a rectangle frame?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/how-to-create-a-smooth-surface-onto-a-rectangle-frame)